# jquery trim white spaces from number

Tags: jquery, html

I need get length of input value but without white spaces but this code return me lenght with white spaces.

```
<input type="text" name="phoneNumber" class="phoneNumber1">


     $('.phoneNumber1').on('blur', function(){

        var phoneNumber = $(".phoneNumber1").val().length;
        var trimNumber = phoneNumber.toString().replace(/ /g,'');
        var finalCount = parseInt(trimNumber);

        if(finalCount > 9) {
            $(".phoneNumber1").after("<div class='number-denied'>
            Zadávejte bez předvolby</div>");
        }

    }).on('focus', function(){ 
         $(this).next().remove()
    });
```

Comment: You're getting the length before you trim it ...

Comment: i guess you can use js trim function for while space like `var str = "       Hello World!        ";
alert(str.trim().length);`

Comment: You are trimming the length, not the phone number.

Comment: If you don't know you're way around regex, try sites like [regex101](https://regex101.com/)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```js
var phoneNumber = "123 456 9999";
console.log(phoneNumber.replace(/\s+/g, ''));
```

Comment: yes @Taplar, I used string, because the number input from input field returns string value which has to be changed to number , toString() is not required

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.trim()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/)

```
$.trim(' 12 3 ')
```

will return `'12 3'`